# java code to Override two spinners in the same layout and activity?

Tags: java, android

I am able to modify my first spinner but not sure how to do the second one in java.  Here is what I am trying, I get no blanent errors but my apk fc's when I launch the activity.  Could someone help me with what java code should like when you overide two things in the same layout and the same acvity?  Thanks in advance.  (now back to searching for an example)

```
package com.wbhome.mytrial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class m5isoActivity extends m5Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.scores);

        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_pbar_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.iso_pbar_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);    
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    

        localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        {   
        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_sp_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.iso_sp_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);    
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    

        localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);}

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did alot of his, hope it helps

```
Spinner m1ssspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_ss_spinner);        
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1ssadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_ss_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
m1ssadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
m1ssspinner.setAdapter(m1ssadapter); 

Spinner m1sqs1spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.m1_sqs1_spinner);        
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m1sqs1adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.m1_sqs1_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            
m1sqs1adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            
m1sqs1spinner.setAdapter(m1sqs1adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your compiler works, it should points red warnings (errors), because you're creating two Spinners with the same name and the same thing for ArrayAdapter. At least change the variable's names.

Comment: I thought Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_sp_spinner);  and     Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_pbar_spinner); and the array list info where the only changes.  I would appreciate an example of what you mean.

Comment: The compiler is fine. The second variable is in another scope.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initializer blocks! Line up your `{`'s and `}`'s, so you see where your methods, code blocks and classes start and end.

```
public class m5isoActivity extends m5Activity {//start of class

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    //start of method
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.scores);

        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_pbar_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.iso_pbar_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);    
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    

        localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        } //onCreate method ends here

        {   //following code is a initalizer block, 
            //you should move this into a method
        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_sp_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.iso_sp_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);    
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);    

        localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);}//end of initializer block

    }//end of class
```

Comment: public class m5isoActivity extends m5Activity {//start of class    @Override    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    //start of method        super.onCreate(R.layout.scores);        Spinner localSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.iso_pbar_spinner);        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.iso_pbar_list, R.layout.my_normal_spinner_style);            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);            localSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);